# I am using jquery to append additional form selections and inputs. If I come back to the form the appended inputs do not appear

Tags: jquery, forms

This is my append function:

```
function addMR() {
    //console.log('running addMR')
    //current keeps track of how many moving radar inputs there are
    current = parseInt(current) + 1;
    g_current = parseInt(g_current) + 1;
    var strToAdd = 'a select and 3 text inputs here - very long'
    $('#movingradarDiv').append(strToAdd)
}
```

and it works correctly.

Here is the form code that calls the append function:

```
 <input type="button" id="addMR" value="Add Moving Radar">
```

Appending the inputs works correctly, and the appended inputs are correctly posted with the form, but if I have to come back to the form to make changes the appended inputs no longer appear.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to prevent it?

Comment: 'but if I have to come back to the form' - from where?

Comment: Submits to a review page, then back to the form if changes are necessary. BACK button or js function.

Comment: The web is stateless. It has no way of remembering anything unless you create some way for it to do so, like a database, cookies, localStorage, etc.

Comment: The thing is that when you "come back" the for gets reloaded from the original source, and all the jQuery interaction that was done to that DOM, didn't exist at that point. if you are going back using the "Go Back" button on the browser, you need to create a cookie to keep a session state and remember the changes, if is a form validation process, you could send some flags or check the information that was send to see its state before "send"...

Comment: Diego, can you point me to an example of this? I thing it will help with a new issue.  Thanks.l

Comment: I have a fix for the issue of the inputs disappearing if you come back to the form.  What I have found now is that if I attempt to submit but but the validation fails and the js returns false, I can still see the appended inputs but I can no longer remove them with the following function: `function deleteT1MR() {
    //don't do anything unless there's more thatn 1 t1mr input
  if(t1current > 1){
    t1current = parseInt(t1current) - 1;
    g_t1current = parseInt(g_t1current) - 1;  
    $('#movingradarDiv div:last-child').remove();
  }
}`

Comment: This function to remove the appended inputs works correctly before I attempt to submit the form.  I assume the DOM loses track of the child divs added to the named parent div?  Does someone know a way to track this and what I need to reset so this function will continue to remove a last child after an attempted form submission?  Thank you.